# how to install ftdi drivers in beagle bone black for communication

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to communicate an android device with beaglebone black.But the application should not detect the beagle bone black device.Can any one help me what are the procedures are used before an application is run in Beagle Board.

Thank you !

Comment: Whats your OS platform ? You want to communicate via HMI , adb , or serial console ? Please post necessary details ...

Comment: I installed only android os in beaglebone black.And the communication via usb cable

Comment: Beaglebone black and android device via usb cable

Comment: Where is the ftdi chip?  Which device is the USB host?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect BBB to **putty to get Serial Console** , by using the following configuration .
[image]

You will also get `adb shell`

Open a command prompt & type command "`adb shell`" & press Enter

Have a read : [Link](http://beagleboard.org/static/beaglebone/latest/README.htm)

Comment: in the command prompt it should seems that   
C:\>adb shell
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
   what to do?

Comment: Did you added the path of adb.exe in environment variables.

Comment: ya... the adb shell is worked and should get  "root@beagleboneblack :/ #"   then i should install the 32 bit installer and trying to open the http://192.168.7.2/.but it returns 
"This web page is not available"

Comment: Can you please  tell the further procedures to communicate the beagleboneblack and android devices because i'm new in android